# how to replace seconds to zero in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  code     time
  1        003002
  1        053003
  1        060002
  1        073001
  1        073003
```

I want to generate following dataframe in pandas

```
  code     time        new_time
  1        003002      00:30:00
  1        053003      05:30:00
  1        060002      06:00:00
  1        073001      07:30:00 
  1        073003      07:30:00
```

I am doing it with following code

```
df['new_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] ,format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H%M%S').dt.floor('T').dt.time
```

Or remove last 2 values by indexing, then change format to `%H%M`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].str[:-2], format='%H%M').dt.time

print (df)
  code      time
0    1  00:30:00
1    1  05:30:00
2    1  06:00:00
3    1  07:30:00
4    1  07:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using astype:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_oclh.Time).astype('datetime64[m]').dt.time
```

`'datetime64[m]'` symbolizes the time we want to convert to which is datetime with minutes being the largest granulariy of time wanted. Alternatively you could use [s] for seconds (rid of milliseconds) or [H] for hours (rid of minutes, seconds and milliseconds)